# Getting an error when trying to send an object with a List<> attribute to a Web-Api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a user object

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfAchievements { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Uid { get; set; }

    private List<Achievement> _listOfAllAchievements;
    public List<Achievement> ListOfAllChievements
    {
        get
        {
            return _listOfAllAchievements;
        }

        set
        {
            _listOfAllAchievements = value;
            NumberOfAchievements = _listOfAllAchievements.Count();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I want to send the data to a Web-Api in json format via a Put request:

```
_httpClient = new HttpClient();
_httpClient.BaseAddress = _webApiUri;
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

try
{
   HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(url, user);

   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
   throw new AggregateException(e);
}
```

This is the controller which receives the data
`UserController.cs`

```
public void PutUser(int id, User user)
{
   user.Id = id;

   if (!userRepository.UpdateUser(user))
   {
      throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
   }
}
```

Everytime I call `PutAsJsonAsync` this error message shows up

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

But when I change

```
private List<Achievement> _listOfAllAchievements;
public List<Achievement> ListOfAllChievements { get; set; }
```

to

```
private IEnumerable<Achievement> _listOfAllAchievements;
public IEnumerable<Achievement> ListOfAllChievements { get; set; }
```

the error disappears.
I've searched the web but couldn't find an answer why I can't send a `List<>` in json format. Is there someone out there who knows an answer to this question?
Because when using `IEnumerable` the list gets in the right way serialized while sending (I looked at it with *Fiddler*), but the received object in the controller has an empty list. So something goes wrong while deserialization.
I can't figure out why.

I'm not that experienced in working with Web-Api and data in json format. So I guess that that is a stupid question, but as I said I couldn't find an answer.

**Summary**

Why am i getting an error when trying to send an object with an `List<>` as attribute to a Web-Api

Why do I lose the data of my `IEnumerable<>` list while deserialization on the Web-Api

***Edit***
Ok I've narrowed down the error source. Everytime an user achieves an achievement I call a method to show a *toast* notification in this method I add the achievement to the `AchievementList` of the user.

```
if (App.User.ListOfAllAchievements == null)
   App.User.ListOfAllAchievements = new List<Achievement>();

App.User.ListOfAllAchievements.Add(achievement);
```

Now while the error above is thrown the program jumps into this *toast* method for whatever reason. So the achievement get added again (when looking in debug mode at the newest added item in the list the debugger crashes). I debugged it step by step and there is no single line of code calling this *toast* method in the section where the error is thrown. I only call this method in one place from another method and this method which calls the toast method doesn't get called. It's like magic which is very very strange.
This is how I workaround the error (I've absolute no idea why this makes the error disappear):

```
if (App.User.ListOfAllAchievements == null)
   App.User.ListOfAllAchievements = new List<Achievement>();

var list = App.User.ListOfAllAchievements.ToList();
list.Add(achievement);
App.User.ListOfAllAchievements = list;
```

But the deserialization of the sent object still doesn't work properly. The `ListOfAllAchievements` is still empty, after receiving it in the Web-Api controller.

Comment: Is anyone else accessing this specific user while you're sending the request?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No, all further interaction with the specific user has stopped before sending the request. So only the Put request is accessing this user.

Comment: Two things I want you to try. First, try calling `_listOfAllAchievements.Count` instead of `Count()`. Second, try removing the call completely (just for the sake of the test) and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed, I've tried it with both `IEnumerable<>` and `List<>`.

Comment: Well, the exception isn't lying. Someone is modifying the list while it's being enumerated for serialization. Perhaps there's something you haven't added to the question?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I will try to do it another way I can't figure out which code section causes my error. But thank you for your help.